# Omiagent is consuming almost all the memory in centos VM

Tags: memory-leaks, centos, azure-monitoring

On Azure a few of my VMs are suffering from the omiagent suddenly consuming too much memory up to 60-70% or more.
What can I do to prevent that.

Right now all I can do is restart omiagent.

sudo scxadmin -restart

Do you have any tips or solution ?

Thanks in advance

Cyril